# Ping Command and Domains

Tags: dns, ping

I always thought a domain was a collection of machines related in some way. When I ping a domain name, like google.com, how come just one IP address is returned? What is this IP referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote [centos.org BIND documentation](http://centos.org/docs/2/rhl-rg-en-7.2/s1-bind-configuration.html):

```
Zone File Resource Records

...

    A — Address record, which specifies an IP address to assign to a name.

    <host>     IN     A     <IP-address>

    Figure 14-7. Sample A record configuration

    If the <host> value is omitted, then an A record points to a default IP address for the top of the namespace. This system will be the target of all non-FQDN requests.

    Consider the following A record examples for the domain.com zone file:

                 IN     A       10.0.1.3
    server1      IN     A       10.0.1.5
```

In the above, 10.0.1.3 is the IP of the domain. E.g. if the above was the zone file for domain `example.com`, `ping example.com` would ping 10.0.1.3. Each domain has this "default" IP address and, as is the case with `server1` above, other IPs.

As a side note, you can have multiple IPs pointed by the same DNS name - this is used for load balancing (see e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) or [this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSNameServerLoadBalancing.htm)). To see this, doo `nslookup google.com`.

Answer (score 0):

A domain name is simply a human-friendly pointer to an IP address.

The IP address is referring to the address of the machine that particular domain name points to. This is determined by using [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).
Some larger domains, like google.com, do indeed have many IP addresses associated with them, for redundancy reasons. Because these additional IP addresses are assumed to return the same content, most programs, including `ping`, just return an arbitrary one.  If you wanted to see all these IP address, you can use the [dig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28Command%29) program.